# Problem with open graph when posting to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to integrate open graph in my website, so that I can post a link to my relevant facebook page and it will display the relevant information (title, description etc).

Yet, even though it worked for some time, now it only displays my domain name regardless of the link I post. No images, no descs, nothing.

I've created a test page to find out what's wrong, but I've come to a dead end.
The test page is W3C valid, the Facebook debugger is parsing all the information correctly, the preview before I post the link to facebook is correct, but when I hit post it displays nothing, just the url.

I've tried several actions such as different doctypes, commenting out the open graph metas, moving js after the metas, removing the meta content-type to no avail, but if you can help me post the test page correctly to facebook, I think I'll be able to find what's wrong with my site.

My website: http://www.accorda.info
The test page: http://www.accorda.info/test.html
My facebook fan page: http://www.facebook.com/accorda.info

Answer (score 0):

Replace the meta tag or delete some. I don't understand… Facebook OpenGraph Debug tool show IMBb info for your page.
 http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.accorda.info%2Ftest.html

Remember, Facebook don't update page info real-time. New meta tags can be visible in 2 days.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I've entered the meta tags from the example provided by facebook at my test page.
I think that the debugger updates the facebook cache for the page. 
As I said, my problem is when posting to the facebook page. Although in the preview the information is displayed correctly (before hitting the post), after the post nothing is displayed except the domain name.

Comment: Place your info and delete all "admin" meta tags and app_id. And wait 2 days, or create new test page, and then first check Debug Facebook tools.

Comment: I created a new page (www.accorda.info/test3.html) with my information, without admin or app_id tags, but the same thing happens :/